# Websockets : Send message from php server to clients

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, broadcast, phpwebsocket

I'm trying to send messages from my file index.php (server) to clients connected using websockets.

My javascript file to create the client connection :

```
var websocket_server = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4950/");
websocket_server.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("connected");
}
websocket_server.onmessage = function(e)
{
  console.log('message received from server');
}
```

index.php:

```
$msg = "Message from server";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,1) or die("prbl options\n");
socket_connect($sock, '127.0.0.1', 4950) or die("could not connect\n");
socket_write($sock, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

The client connect to the websocket is successful, but when I run the PHP file, I get nothing (no error and no message in the console).

In other words, javascript doesn't consider my socket_write as a message :/

Any ideas? :)

Comment: This isn't really how websockets work. Even if your code worked, the socket wouldn't be persistent, so wouldn't be much use. Unless you really want to make your own websocket server as an academic exercise, then I suggest you should just use a ready-made websocket library such as ratchet or one of the others.

Comment: ratchet does the opposite, send data from clients to server (who then sends it to other clients). In fact, I will need the ZeroMQ library for my project, but the lib isn't available anymore :/

I don't need the socket to be persistent on the server side

Comment: "ratchet does the opposite" ...websockets are two-way. Ratchet can send from server to client - you just said it yourself, in fact.

Comment: And you _do_ need the socket to be persistent, otherwise how is the client supposed to stay connected to it and wait for a message to arrive?

Comment: To be more specific on my problem, I have a Ratchet file running in the background (persistant) and a js file who connects clients to ratchet. But I need to send websocket messages from another php file this time not persistant :) I'm trying to do something close to what the ZeroMQ library did

Comment: Ratchet waits for clients to send messages to do something (onMessage function), this time I want the server to decide

Comment: Yes it does, but there's really nothing to stop you sending messages to clients from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: How ? that's my problem ^^

Comment: Look at the hello word demo here: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world - notice that when a client connects, you add them to a `$clients` collection. And then you can use $client->send to send to any specific client. In the example, $clients is protected within the class, but to me there's no obvious reason why this class couldn't expose them as public, or at least have a public method which other classes can use to access that and send a message

Comment: P.S. if you don't like / want to work with websockets, if you're only ever sending server -> client, then Server Sent Events might be simpler to implement. I don't know this one specifically but a 2 minute google reveals a simple-looking implementation: https://github.com/hhxsv5/php-sse

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I will try both methods see if it works :)

Comment: I've tried to set $clients to public but it doesn't seem to work because i need to pass all the SplObjectStorage. And for the SSE, js request the page in a loop and that's a problem for what i'm trying to do :/

Comment: "doesn't seem to work because i need to pass all the SplObjectStorage" ...not sure what this means. Did you have a specific error?

Comment: " js request the page in a loop"...not sure what this means either. There's no looping in the javascript in the SSE scenario.

Comment: SSE :  client makes only a single request and the server keeps pushing data to the client continuously. In my case i want to push data only when I decide to (when the server decides to)

Comment: For Ratchet, the connections aren't stored in the variable $clients but in the SplObjectStorage $this->clients using MessageComponentInterface, and i can't access it outside the script :/

Comment: Again, "can't" means what? You get an error? It would help to see some actual code and errors

Comment: "the server keeps pushing data to the client continuously"...that's because that demo keep deliberately generating random numbers to send to the client. Notice the comment where it says "get news from database or server" - the idea is that some other bit of your code would have written a message into a table or event queue, and that the SSE loop keeps checking that queue for new messages (i.e. ones it hasn't sent yet) - instead of the hard-coded message included in the demo -  and if it finds one it will send it, if it doesn't, it'll just keeping looping until it does.

Comment: I haven't shared the code of my ratchet attemps because they already are topics on this (left unanswered or leaving us with ZMQ or disappointing solutions) and I felt like this was a little off subject, But it would definetely be  a better solution than SSE !! So please let me know as soon as you find a way to do it :D !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution thanks to @ADyson ;)
I'm using SSE server sent events now and it works !But I'd like to know if my code is 'proper' or if there is a more 'adequate' way.

I'm using session superglobals to pass server informations changes to another file which is constantly reading it as event-stream (that's the way SSE works).

index.php :

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="stream.js">
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
      <a>Receive message</a>
        </body>
      </html>
```

stream.js (listening to the server) :

```
var serv = new EventSource("server.php");

  serv.onmessage = function(e) {
      var jdata = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log(jdata.message);
  };

  serv.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log('Connection opened');
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
      receive_msg();
    });
  });

  function receive_msg(){
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'controller.php',
     data: {action: 'send'}
   });
  }
```

controller.php :

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
  $_SESSION['server']="you have received a message";
}
```

server.php :

```
    <?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');


if (isset($_SESSION['server'])) {
  $data = array(
      'message'=> $_SESSION['server']
  );
  $data = json_encode($data);
  echo "data: {$data}\n\n";
  unset($_SESSION['server']);
}
```

The way it works :

Clients connect to the server.php and read the file constantly. When the server wants to send a message to clients, it creates a session variable. Server.php reads the variable and pass it to my js file. Then the variable is destroyed so we pass the message only once.

Comment: that looks like a reasonable solution. If it's good enough for you, then the extra complexity of websockets probably isn't necessary

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. With this, the server send message to 1 client. If every client listen to server.php then everybody gets a message but each one gets unique message because the script launch with a session variable. I need something else than the session variable to tell server.php to send a message. Do you have ideas ?

Comment: a variable shared by every clients but that cannot be in a database (i'm not going to send sql request every 5sec :/)

Comment: you could use something like an event or message queue. e.g. on windows you could use MSMQ. On linux there are probably similar technologies. P.S. "i'm not going to send sql request every 5sec"...why not? If the query is simple (e.g. just read 1 record from this table whose timestamp is later than the time I last requested it) and the table is correctly indexed, it should take milliseconds - it's not really a heavy load on a sql box unless it's very very under-resourced. And anyway you always need to scale your app and db to the expected load, that's just how it is.

Comment: I'm thinking about using websockets right after the onmessage in SSE. One client receives a message and then Ratchet shares it with every one. However, websockets can be used by everyone who visits my app inside their console. And I don't want them to send sockets messages pretending to be from the server.

Comment: Oh I thought the sql querry would be slow and CPU consumming. Then I guess I'll try that ;)

Comment: The SQL query will only be slow and CPU consuming if you don't design the table and query correctly, and/or if your SQL server isn't scaled correctly to the number of expected users :-)

Comment: Are websockets faster than sql queries ? Maybe I'll go with websockets and use openssl_encrypt to send a code via the server. A client receives a message, then he shares it with other clients with the code. Ratchet receives the message and decrypt it. That way I'll know for sure that the message is indeed from the server. What do you think ?

Comment: "Are websockets faster than sql queries"...you're comparing apples and pears, they have totally different purposes. Your websocket+SSE proposal is, frankly, bonkers - no offence. Don't rely on a client to do the server's job. And if you encrypt something within the browser, the technique can still be copied by someone malicious because all the JS source code is visible. Try the SQL method and see if it gives you an _actual_ performance issue rather than just fretting about it.